Use Function in React
I have this progress bar as a div
import React from 'react'
import logo from "../img/Madcor_Icon.png"

function Snackbar() {
  return (
    <div>
      <figure className='notification'>
            <div className='notification__body'>

                Das Profil wurde erfolgreich angelegt  
                <img src={logo}
                    title='Erfolgreich'
                    alt='Erfolgreich'
                    className='notification__icon'
                />
            </div>
            <div className='notification__progress'></div>
        </figure>   
    </div>
  );
}

export default Snackbar;

I want to show the div (Progress Bar) if the registration on Firebase Auth worked.
function RegistrationForm() {

    const handleSumbit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        const emailReg = e.target.emailReg.value
        const passwordReg = e.target.passwordReg.value

        createUserWithEmailAndPassword(database,emailReg,passwordReg)
        .then((userCredential) => {
            // Signed in 
            var user = userCredential.user;
            alert(user);
            // ...
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            alert(error)
            // ..
          });
    }
return


I tried to start the function like this, but I think that's the wrong way.
I'm new to react and not the best one in JS but I want to learn :)
import React from 'react'
import "../styles/forms.css";
import { database } from '../data/FirebaseConfig';
import { createUserWithEmailAndPassword } from "firebase/auth";
import Snackbar from './snackbar';

function RegistrationForm() {

    const handleSumbit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        const emailReg = e.target.emailReg.value
        const passwordReg = e.target.passwordReg.value

        createUserWithEmailAndPassword(database,emailReg,passwordReg)
        .then((userCredential) => {
            // Signed in 
            var user = userCredential.user;
            alert(user);
            **Snackbar()**
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            alert(error)
            // ..
          });
    }

Can someone explain to me how I have to do this? Is it right that I have to import the function?
Thanks a lot for you help
greets Primo

To do conditional rendering in React, you would typically want to create a piece of state that determines whether the component is rendered, and then just manipulate that piece of state.
So for instance...
import { useState } from "react";
import Snackbar from "./Snackbar";

function RegistrationForm() {
   [showProgressBar, setShowProgressBar] = useState(false);

   function handleSubmitSuccess() {
      setShowProgressBar(true);
   }

   return (
      <>
         {some other jsx}
         {showProgressBar && <Snackbar />}
      </>
   );
}

The conditional rendering method here (using the &&) is called short circuiting, where it doesn't move to the next part of the expression unless showProgressBar is true.
The change in state will cause a re-render of the component, and during this render it will mount the Snackbar component due to the short circuit.

Thank you for your help :) now i know what do do concerning this issue :)
